# bitbake do_rootfs install fails with shared library symlink in bbappend

Tags: symlink, rpm, yocto, udev, bitbake

I am trying to add a shared library package to a Yocto Krogoth image from a custom recipe that is dependent on `libudev.so.0` but the *openembedded-core* layer's `eudev` [recipe](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/47683/) only provides `libudev.so.1.6.3` and a `libudev.so.1` symlink: 
  `libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.3`

I have added a `eudev_%.bbappend` *recipes_core* recipe that creates the symlink

```
do_install_append() {
        ln -srf ${D}${base_libdir}/libudev.so.1 ${D}${base_libdir}/libudev.so.0
}
```

and I can confirm the `libudev.so.0` file is added to the *libudev* package in

```
tmp/work/HOST/eudev/3.1.5-r0/image/lib/libudev.so.0 
tmp/work/HOST/eudev/3.1.5-r0/package/lib/libudev.so.0 
tmp/work/HOST/eudev/3.1.5-r0/packages-split/lib/libudev.so.0 
tmp/work/HOST/eudev/3.1.5-r0/sysroot-destdir/lib/libudev.so.0
```

and installed to the image's `tmp/sysroots/MACHINE/lib/libudev.so.0` directory when building the image and is present in the resultant `tmp/deploy/images/MACHINE/IMAGENAME.tar.bz2` rootfs archive. The issue is that with the above in place I cannot add my shared library package to the image as it results in the following error:

```
do_rootfs: ...
Computing transaction...error: Can't install MYRECIPE@HOST: no package provides libudev.so.0
```

The custom recipe does have `RDEPENDS_${PN} = libudev` set.

Why is the *do_rootfs* error generated as the installed `libudev` package clearly does provide the `libudev.so.0` library? Bitbaking the custom recipe independently has no issue, but that obviously does not attempt to install the resultant package into an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the do_rootfs error generated as the installed libudev package
>   clearly does provide the libudev.so.0 library?

I'm pretty sure the the relevant code isn't looking at file names but actual symbols needed by your library -- there's packaging magic that looks at all the libraries and executables and figures out their runtime dependencies based on the symbols they need (this is how the correct dependency libraries end up on the rootfs). I believe the error message is trying to say that no available library exports the symbols that your library needs.

You can check the soname your udev exports with

```
readelf -a libudev.so.1 | grep SONAME
0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libudev.so.1]
```

I've not confirmed that this is what the rootfs code checks for but it's quite likely.

Are you expecting a library linked with libudev.so.0 to just work with libudev.so.1 without even a recompile? I'm not familiar with udev but in general libraries are unlikely to work like that.

> The custom recipe does have RDEPENDS_${PN} = libudev set.

This is not normally needed -- if your software dynamically links to a library, the runtime dependency is found automatically.

Comment: I assumed the packaging system is looking for more than file names, but I assumed that adding the symlink for `libudev.so.0` would suffice as when manually copying and using the library on the target system it works fine with that. Interestingly the library's SDK documentation directly refers to the naming of libudev.so:
"For example, the actual installed libudev library may be named libudev.so.0,
and a link may be necessary:
Build:$ sudo ln -s /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libudev.so.1
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libudev.so"
So there is nothing more to be done in the .bbappend then?

Comment: That documentation comment is probably not entirely correct and should not refer to so.0 in the text -- you can see how the actual symlink they use in the example does _not_ link so.0 to so.1.

Comment: I've noted that typo yes, but actually the lib does require libudev.so.0 rather than libudev.so.1 in practice

Comment: Regarding the SONAME exported by my `libudev.so.0` I can confirm it is:
libudev.so.1 with the readelf check, so it is most likely the issue. During the do_rootfs command the rpm package manager is on control of installing the packages (see [yocto-reference-manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#image-generation-dev-environment)) so I assume I would have to find a way of bypassing the package manager's dependency check or do a manual file copy post package installation using `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND`

Comment: hi Francois, were you able to solve your issue, I am also facing similar issue. Please let know how to solve it.

Comment: Three choices, either you fix your custom recipe to have a dependency on whatever the version of udev available at build time. Or if it's precompiled, run patchelf on one of your custom recipe's library to fix the version used for libudev. Or, at least in newer version, silence the warning with `INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "file-rdeps"`.